# All communication apps show "Unfortunately, X has stopped."?

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, crashes

My phone is having a weird problem, whenever I get communication from anywhere (e.g. e-mail and sms), I get greeted with "Unfortunately, X has stopped." with X representing the application that handles the communication. The weird thing is, after showing that pop up, I can still use the application without problem.

Let's say somebody texts me, that error will pop out but when I click on the notification, the SMS opens up without a problem. So far it hasn't affected anything (yet) but you can imagine the annoyance of seeing that pop up every time someone contacts you.

What should I do?

Comment: Not sure what the problem really *is*, but you could try to delete the affected app's cache (via the system's menu *apps->manage apps*), maybe something got messed up there.